# Remove old handler and connect new handler inside Sub

Tags: vb.net, events, handler

I want to make a Sub that connect a event to a function
Before it does that I want te remove the old event.

This is what I have so far, I know it must be something in this direction
but I keep getting an error 
BC30577: 'AddressOf' operand must be the name of a method (without parentheses).

```
    Delegate Sub DelegateType()

    Private Sub ConnectButtonWithEvent(ByRef Button As CommandButton, ByRef newFunctionAdres As DelegateType)   
        Static OldEvent As DelegateType
        Static OldButton As CommandButton   

        If Not OldButton Is Nothing Then
            RemoveHandler OldButton.Click, AddressOf OldEvent
        End If 

        AddHandler Button.Click, AddressOf newFunctionAdres 

        OldEvent = AddressOf newFunctionAdres
        OldButton = Button
    End Sub
```

Comment: Couple of things - does the correct address get passed to your `AddHandler` statement in the first place? Have you tested it? Secondly, the signature for a button is not as you've specified for your `DelegateType` delegate sub.

Comment: First: No I could not even compile this. For the second: I have tried this :     Public Delegate Sub DelegateType(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)   In another attempt i have removed the AddressOf function in the Add/RemoveHandler but then the compiler tells me it cannot convert Delagate type to System.Eventhandler.

Comment: I have also tried to pass the newFunctionAdres as Eventhandler. This works for adding an new event to a button, but I am unable to store this eventhandler so I could remove it from the button in the next call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folowing works for me...

```
Private Sub test(ByVal btn As Button, ByVal fad As EventHandler)
    AddHandler btn.Click, fad
End Sub


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    test(tb, AddressOf ClickHandler)
End Sub

Private Sub ClickHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    'Do nothing
End Sub
```

The problem was simply the type of the argument you used to pass the delegate over - it should have been `EventHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx!

That fixed it
For other members this is the final code:

```
Private Sub ConnectButtonWithEvent(ByRef Button As VisiWinNET.Forms.CommandButton, ByRef     newFunctionAdres As EventHandler)

        Static OldEvent As EventHandler         
        Static OldButton As VisiWinNET.Forms.CommandButton

        If Not OldButton Is Nothing Then
            RemoveHandler OldButton.Click, OldEvent
        End If

        AddHandler Button.Click, newFunctionAdres

        OldEvent = newFunctionAdres
        OldButton = Button
    End Sub
```